# How to extract numeric fields from splunk log and generate min, max, avg?

Tags: splunk

I have these entries in application log:
API call took 2.340474 seconds

How can I extract the value of response time and generate min, max and avg stats?

I tried this but I am not getting any results
API CALL call took | rex "call took: (?.*) seconds" | stats MIN(apitime)

I think the extraction of field is not working with my regex. 
What would be the right way of extracting my response time and generating statistics?

Answer (score 2):

You need to name the field in the rex command:

```
rex "call took: (?<apitime>.*) seconds"
```

If that still isn't working, simplify your expression and then add complexity bit by bit as needed.  You could start like this:

```
rex "(?<apitime>\w+) seconds"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
API call took | rex field=_raw "call took: (?<apitime>\d+\.\d+) seconds" | stats min(apitime) as min_apitime, max(apitime) as max_apitime, avg(apitime) as avg_apitime
```